# Excel:Sum of numbers in a column with data in each cell having two numbers separated by slash (Eg:12/24)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Currently having data like this for a specific column where it needs both numbers to be shown in a single cell separated by a slash

Is it possible to sum on such a column in Excel

[image]

to get the total at the bottom as 94/76

I tried using

```
=SUM(LEFT(I3,FIND("/",I3)-1):LEFT(I7,FIND("/",I7)-1))
```

Just to see if the part to the left of the slash would get added but it didn't work.

Comment: I would create 2 helper columns, split the left and right then sum and recombine using &.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try `IMSUM()`:

[image]

Formula in `A6`:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(IMSUM(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A4,"/","+")&"i"),"+","/"),"i","")
```

I guess this needs to be CSE-entered if one use an Excel version other than Microsoft365.

Comment: Cool, just if the second value in result is negative, then another ```SUBSTITUTE``` would be needed: ```=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(IMSUM(SUBSTITUTE(J1:J4,"/","+")&"i"),"+","/"),"-","/-"),"i","")``` . The problem will be if the first well to be negative

Comment: @basic, true. That could be a bit harder to crack though if both values would be negative.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this formula to sum the values to the left of the /,

```
=SUM(LEFT(A2:A5,FIND("/",A2:A5)-1)+0)
```

and this to sum the values to the right.

```
=SUM(MID(A2:A5,FIND("/",A2:A5)+1,255)+0)
```

You might need to enter these as array formulas using CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER and you'll probably need to alter the cell references.

Comment: The formula I meant to post for the right hand side does work, and I've fixed the answer.:)

Answer (score 0):

So, based on my comment:

```
=Left(I3,2)*1
```

in one column and dragged down,

and

```
=RIGHT(I3,LEN(I3)-FIND("/",I3,1))*1
```

also dragged down, then in the following row two sums and finally

```
=J9&"/"&K9
```

Assuming the helper columns are J & K. The *1 is to turn text into a value.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may try `FILTERXML()`.

```
=SUM(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1:A4,"/","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[1]")) & "/" & SUM(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1:A4,"/","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[last()]"))
```

[image]